# Javascript clock for jailbroken iPhone Lockscreen

Tags: javascript, iphone, jailbreak

having trouble getting my Javascript right for displaying the time correctly on my HTML Lockscreen.

I've been looking at a couple others and they're not using document.write() but rather document.getElementById() and pushing it to a div.

I've tried two different things, the first one is here:
http://pastebin.com/RT4xcvPt

The problem is that the time never updates unless I unlock my phone and then turn the screen off again. When I wake it, the time is correct. If I let it sit idle for 5 minutes and check the lockscreen again, the time will not have updated at all.

I made a few changes, namely adding setInterval() and this is attempt 2: http://pastebin.com/LfSiUK31

The problem with this is that it goes completely black after 2 seconds. The issue from the first attempt still persists. It never shows back up on the screen until I unlock then lock, and wake it again. Then it stays on for 2 seconds before going black (I made it background-color: #ffffff; for these examples, but on the phone it's set to background-color: #000000; which may be why it's just solid black).

I can style and position the text if I can just find a reliable way to get it to work and have the time refresh when you wake the phone to look at the lockscreen.

Any help?

Comment: You should proabably be using innerHTML also since document.write is a write once solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are changing all document everytime, not h1 nodes. So i changed your code, you can look example link below.

http://jsbin.com/uhafax/1/

Comment: worked like a charm. I will be picking it apart and seeing all the differences between yours and mine so I can make more of these in the future. Thanks for the help!